# Integral property question

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Is $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)dx\right)=\int _a^b\:\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)dx$ always true??

It works when $f(x) = e^{arctanx}$  and $a=0 , b=1$, that's why I wanted to know.

Comment: The first integral is zero.

Comment: Wouldnt it be $f(b) - f(a)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

This is in general false. A definite integral is a number, not a funtion. Or, as a function, it is the *constant* function, so the left derivative is zero:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)dx\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int _a^b\:f\left(s\right)ds\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int _a^b\:f\left(z\right)dz\right)=\ldots=0
$$
 In order to have an equality, also the second member has to be zero, i.e.
$$
0=\int _a^b\:\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)dx=f(b)-f(a).
$$

Comment: Maybe I didn't expressed it well. I meant in a case like this:                                         $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int _0^1\:e^{\arctan \left(x\right)}dx\right)=\int _0^1\:\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{\arctan \left(x\right)}\right)dx $  I got $e^{\frac{\pi }{4}}-1$ for both, but is it just coincidence then?

Comment: The first member is simply 0, not $e^{\pi/4}$, for the reason I have explained. The integration variable is DUMB.

Answer (score 1):

No. $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ is a constant, it does not depend on $x$, so its derivative is equal to $0$. On the other hand, the right hand side of your equality is the integral of $f'$ and its value is $f(b)-f(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

The integral on the left is a constant number like 5. When you differentiate a constant number with respect to a variable you get 0. So the left-hand side equal 0.
The right hand side is the integral over derivative of a function. The function could be anything like $f(x)=x$ in which case its derivative is 1 and the integral of $1$ from $a$ to $b$ would be equal to $b-a$. So no equality there.

Answer (score 0):

If the function $f\in C^1([a,b],\mathbb R)$, The second integral will give $f(b)-f(a)$.